# Why are the limits of integration of $\Gamma (z)$ the way they are?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

$$\Gamma (z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt$$ To make things easier, let's call this $G(z)$. If we take the derivative with respect to $t$ of both sides, we get $\frac {dG(z)}{dt}=\frac {d}{dt} [\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt]=0$ . The reason why I think this equals zero is because if we are just looking at $\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt$ , $z$ is fixed and this definite integral is equal to a constant (if it's convergent). If $\frac {dG(z)}{dt}=0$ , this implies that $G(z)=C\cdot t^0$ , so it looks like $G(z)$ is absolutely independent of the value of $t$ . Why then does $G$ have those specific limits of integration? Those limits, only affect $t$ , which $G$ is independent of. And I know that this is illogical because by my argument the limits of integration could even be equal to each other, which would obviously lead to a false solution. Thanks.

My background just Calculus $1$ so please don't use infinite series and such.

If you are interested in my motivation, the original motivation for this question is that I wanted to see if it is possible to have an elementary function $f(x)$ that that grows faster than $x!$ (please don't tell me the answer to this or give any hints, I wanna see if I can do this by myself). The motivation of THAT question was to see if it is even possible to have an elementary function of a finite number of terms that models $x!$ (again, please don't tell me the answer to that either.)

Comment: There's a thing called paragraphs. They really make mathematics much easier to read.

Comment: Also, it is almost always better to lead with the question, not with preamble, motivation,etc. If Joe is browsing the site for questions he can answer, he wants to quickly weed out the ones that he doesn't feel competent to answer. By burying the question, you make it very hard to do that. This will actually cause people who *can* answer your question to skip it. Start with the question, then explain your motivation, if you must.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That should be better now. I included the motivation because everybody says so on meta.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I haven't thought of question writing that way before, but now that I have, I really like your suggestions. Thanks for posting that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dt} G(z)=0$ because, as a function of $t$, it is a constant. If $F(z)=z$, then $\frac{d}{dt}F(z)=0$, too. There is no free variable $t$ in the definition of $\Gamma$.

It is sometimes confusing notation to the uninitiated, but the $t$ inside the integral is really a placeholder, indicating what is changing - it only exists inside the integral.

Now, the step you are doing is a bit confusing, because you can't bring $d/dt$ from outside the interval, where $t$ is "unbound" and move it inside the integral, where $t$ is "bound." It simply can't be done, and there is no reason to think you can.

If you don't believe me, try it with other functions.  It simply won't work. For example, $F(z)=\int_0^1 t^z dt = \frac{1}{1+z}$. Then, by your reason, $\frac{d}{dt} F = \int_0^1 zt^{z-1} dt = 1$. That doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: If $F(z)=z$, isn't $\frac{d}{dt}F(z)= \frac {dz}{dt}$

Comment: $z$ is not a function of $t$.

Comment: ok thanks now I got it

Answer (score 3):

I think your real question got lost in here with the $d/dt$ conundrum. Integrate by parts and see what happens. And note that $\Gamma(1)$ has a very nice value because of the $0$ and $\infty$ limits of integration. Another reasonable question you might have asked is what $x!$ should mean when $x$ isn't a positive integer.

Comment: But the crux of his problem is the misunderstanding about $d/dt$. He doesn't say he has any problem with the proof that $\Gamma$ satisfies the functional equation, only this problem with $d/dt$ which seems to make the whole function nonsense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Maybe. He asked why the specific limits were chosen. I chose to avoid the wild goose chase you'd already addressed. :) I see that he accepted your answer after I wrote mine, so clearly your interpretation was the right one.